# What is the easiest way to extract the data from this string with matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-parsing

I have a text-file which contains data formatted like this:

```
000000:11.315 2049.000000
000000:11.320 2050.000000
000000:11.327 2048.000000
000000:11.333 2050.000000
000000:11.338 2049.000000
000000:11.348 2048.000000
```

How can I extract the data into three arrays? I've played around with `textscan`, but I was not able to figure out a proper format-string that worked. (The number of lines is of course not 6, but arbitrary.)

Comment: scannedData = textscan(fid, '%f:%f %f', 'CollectOutput', true)

Comment: @zellus: You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('dat.txt');
scannedData = textscan(fid, '%f:%f %f', 'CollectOutput', true) 
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: To make it clear how to extract the 3 arrays, you could add three more lines like `arrayN = scannedData{1}(:,N)` where N would be either 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I didn't know what cells are. I'm new to matlab.